# Android App Digital Persona couldn't find "libdpfr6.so"

Tags: android, digital, persona

I am developing an Android App that uses fingerprint reader Digital Persona 4500 UareU.
When I trying to get the readers I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
        dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList
        [[zip file "/data/app/com.zaimella.enrollment-1/base.apk"],
        nativeLibraryDirectories=[
        /data/app/com.zaimella.enrollment-1/lib/arm, 
        /system/lib, 
        /vendor/lib]]] 
        couldn't find "libdpfr6.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
    at com.digitalpersona.uareu.jni.Dpfpdd.<init>(Dpfpdd.java:43)
    at com.digitalpersona.uareu.dpfpdd.ReaderCollectionImpl.<init>(ReaderCollectionImpl.java:24)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at com.digitalpersona.uareu.UareUGlobal.GetReaderCollection(UareUGlobal.java:39)
```

Please HELP !!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The SOLUTION !!!

1.- Install DigitalPersona SDK

2.- Get jniLibs from the installation: `DigitalPersona\U.are.U SDK\Android\bin\android-21`

3.- You must include the jniLibs folder into your project. See picture 1

4.- `Build -> Make Project`

5.- Be sure that jniLibs are included into your apk file. See picture 2

6.- Install the App using `"adb install"`

7.- BE HAPPY !!!

[jniLibs folder into your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wld7m.png)

[jniLibs folder into your apk file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkWSy.png)

Comment: I've tried this approach and it gives an error:
```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libdpfr6.so'

```
Is it because I have included the aar file also?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I downgraded my gradle plugin to version '3.3.0' as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
}
```